# Create virtual smartcard with pin policy via ITpmVirtualSmartCardManager2 interface

Tags: c#, filesystems, com-interop, smartcard, tpm

Following the instruction of 3.3.4.1 CreateVirtualSmartCardWithPinPolicy (Opnum 5)

I tried to create smartcard with method CreateVirtualSmartCardWithPinPolicy via interface ITpmVirtualSmartCardManager2 and getting an error at TPMVSCMGR_ERROR_GENERATE_FILESYSTEM. Here is the callback statuses that i received:

TPMVSCMGR_STATUS_VTPMSMARTCARD_INITIALIZING,

TPMVSCMGR_STATUS_VTPMSMARTCARD_CREATING,

TPMVSCMGR_STATUS_VGIDSSIMULATOR_INITIALIZING,

TPMVSCMGR_STATUS_VGIDSSIMULATOR_CREATING,

TPMVSCMGR_STATUS_VREADER_INITIALIZING,

TPMVSCMGR_STATUS_VREADER_CREATING,

TPMVSCMGR_STATUS_GENERATE_WAITING,

**TPMVSCMGR_ERROR_GENERATE_FILESYSTEM => error from here. Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).**

Its only happen at one machine of specific user's account until now.

I already tried with "tpmvscmgr.exe create /name "testvsc" /AdminKey DEFAULT /PIN PROMPT" via command prompt as admin and working perfectly so i think there is no problem with TPM

Can somebody let me know the reason why and how to fix it?

Thanks,

Comment: In general, this message means there's a missing .dll file. Either one that you use directly, or one in some dependency. So it's more a deployment issue.

Comment: i could not found any information regarding to this issue as well as which missing dll file. The strange thing is that its only happen at one account on user's machine. Currently we have thousands account are using virtual smartcard

Comment: It just means a dll is missing from this computer. You can use procmon frol sysinternals and filter by file access to check what's the missing file.